lmer: how to find the optimal value of one of the explanatory variables that will give the maximum value of the response variable
I am fitting the following model with the lme4 package in R:
lm_noisyBKG_pr2 <- lmer(ranking ~ slope_diff_value_scaled + slope_diff_sign + slope_target_scaled +  factor(BKG) * I(slope_target_scaled^2) + (1 | stim_ver), data = df_noisy_lmer, REML = FALSE)
where 'factor(BKG)' contains 3 levels.
I would like to have for each of the 'BKG' levels the value of 'slope_target_scaled' that will give me the highest value for the 'ranking' variable.
I tried running the following code however the optimal values I find are quite different from what the graph of the data is showing. Am I doing something wrong here?
# Define prediction function for a specific level of BKG
predict_response <- function(slope_target_scaled_val, bkg_level) {
  new_data <- expand.grid(
    slope_diff_value_scaled = mean(df_noisy_lmer$slope_diff_value_scaled, na.rm = TRUE),
    slope_diff_sign = mean(df_noisy_lmer$slope_diff_sign, na.rm = TRUE),
    slope_target_scaled = slope_target_scaled_val,
    BKG = bkg_level,
    stim_ver = unique(df_noisy_lmer$stim_ver)
  )
  
'# Ensure BKG levels are correct and match the model's levels
new_data$BKG <- factor(new_data$BKG, levels = levels(factor(df_noisy_lmer$BKG)))
  
preds <- predict(lm_noisyBKG_pr2, newdata = new_data, re.form = NA)
return(mean(preds))
}

# Function to find the optimal slope_target_scaled for a specific BKG level
find_optimal_value <- function(bkg_level) {
  result <- optimize(function(x) predict_response(x, bkg_level), 
                     interval = range(df_noisy_lmer$slope_target_scaled, na.rm = TRUE), 
                     maximum = TRUE)
  return(result$maximum)
}

# Find the optimal slope_target_scaled for each BKG level
bkg_levels <- levels(factor(df_noisy_lmer$BKG))
optimal_values <- sapply(bkg_levels, find_optimal_value)

# Create a data frame to show the optimal slope_target_scaled for each BKG level
optimal_df <- data.frame(BKG = bkg_levels, Optimal_slope_target_scaled = optimal_values)

print(optimal_df)

# Calculate the mean and standard deviation of slope_target before scaling
slope_target_mean <- mean(df_noisy_lmer$slope_target, na.rm = TRUE)
slope_target_sd <- sd(df_noisy_lmer$slope_target, na.rm = TRUE)

# Convert scaled values back to original scale
optimal_df$Unscaled_slope_target <- optimal_df$Optimal_slope_target_scaled * slope_target_sd + slope_target_mean

# Print the data frame with unscaled values
print(optimal_df)

Here is an excerpt of the data:



slope_target_scaled
BKG
slope_diff_sig
slope_diff_value_scaled
slope_target_scaled2




-1.5237254
-1
1
0.36023037
2.321739


-1.7776796
-1
1
0.39453802
3.160144


-0.5079085
-2
1
0.66899926
0.257971


-0.7618627
-2
1
0.70330691
0.580434


-1.2697712
-2
1
0.73761457
1.612318


-1.5237254
-2
1
0.77192222
2.321739


-1.7776796
-2
1
0.80622988
3.160144


1.7776796
-3
1
0.84053753
3.160144


1.5237254
-3
1
0.87484518
2.321739


1.2697712
-3
1
0.90915284
1.612318


0.7618627
-3
1
0.94346049
0.580434




It's going to be very difficult for anyone to help you without a [mre], including some reproducible data.
